# The Function Works But Reports this.refresh() is not a function

Tags: javascript, refresh, this

I get this.refresh() is not a function in the error log every time I use this function but it works fine.

Also, when I click on this function for the first time, this.value=undefined. When I click the function again in this form and every other form, the value populates just fine with the previous value.

What could I be doing wrong?

How do I write this function more efficiently?

I still don't quite understand how to use this.value to capture and store a value within an array.

```
function askGender(x) {
    response = "<select class=widgetstyle onClick=_setGender(this.value)><option value=Female>Female<option value=Male>Male</select>";
    characters[x].setGender(response);
    if (this.gender != 0) {
        response = this.gender;
        this.gender = 0;
        characters[x].setGender(response);
    }
}

function _setGender(x) {
    this.gender = x;
    this.refresh();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `this.refresh()` is, in fact, **not a function**.  What do you expect it to be?  Also, it looks like you've forgotten to declare "response" with the `var` keyword.

Comment: Can you post the HTML part along with Javascript at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) so that us mortals can understand your problem ?

Comment: What is x? Who is calling askGender() and _setGender()?

Comment: Is `this.refresh();` supposed to refresh the page? Because you likely want `location.reload();` in that case

Comment: http://kira3696.tripod.com/CombatTracker.rar

Comment: @ren1999 post the relevant bits of your code

Comment: Here is where the game is located http://kira3696.tripod.com/CombatTracker.rar x is an array from 0 to the last characters array number. If I use an alert box "this.refresh() is not a function" does not appear as an error.

Answer (score 0):

`response = "<select class=widgetstyle onClick=_setGender(this.value)><option value=Female>Female<option value=Male>Male</select>";`

look at your response. You set the gender in the click handler. Your misunderstanding on how `this` works.

`this` in `askGender` refers to your character object. When the onClick handler get's called `this` will refer to the DOM object in your `setGender` method.

For the record `.refresh` is a method of his Character object.

The entire code is large and requires thorough debugging. It looks like your editing open source code and trying to use it in a way it was not designed to be used.

Comment: I see. So I'm getting the value of the setGender function when I could be getting the value from the askGender function. How do I capture the option value using one function? Where do I place this.value? Do you have some example code? The function works by clicking on bold text in the form and a field appears there. The user selects Male or Female, clicks out of the field and the field disappears and restores bold text "Female" in its place.

Comment: @ren1999 if you call `this.setGender` it works fine. if you call `_setGender` in the `onClick` it breaks. The easiest solution is to stop handling html as strings and use dom methods but thats a lot of refactoring. I'm not going to do that refactoring for you, i'm afraid.